# BindableEvent Not Firing Lua

Tags: events, lua, roblox

I have a BindableEvent within the ReplicatedStorage in a folder for events, being called from a script in a part, that does not seem to be firing, what could be going wrong?

Code:
Sender(In part):

```
local popEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.PopEvent

local lvl = script.Parent.Parent:GetAttribute("Level")
local pops = game.Workspace.PopParts
local lvlPop = pops:FindFirstChild("Lvl"..tostring(lvl))
local kids = lvlPop:GetChildren()

while true do
    for i, v in pairs(kids) do
        popEvent:Fire(script.Parent, v)
        print("here")
    end
    wait(3)
end
```

Receiver(In folder):

```
script.Parent.Event:Connect(function (pt1, pt2)
    print("there")
    if (pt1:IsA("Part") and pt2:IsA("Part")) then
        local x1 = pt1.Position.X
        local l1 = pt1.Size.X / 2
        local x2 = pt2.Position.X
        local l2 = pt2.Size.X / 2
        
        local z1 = pt1.Position.Z
        local d1 = pt1.Size.Z / 2
        local z2 = pt2.Position.Z
        local d2 = pt2.Size.Z / 2
        
        if ((x1 + l1 < x2 - l2 and x1 - l1 > x2 + l2) and (z1 + d1 < z2 - d2 and z1 - d1 > z2 + d2)) then
            pt1.Transparency = 1
            pt1.Anchored = false
        end
    else
        if not(pt1:IsA("Part")) then
            warn("pt1 isn't a part")
        elseif not(pt2:IsA("Part")) then
            warn("pt2 isn't a part")
        end
    end
end)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've put the Receiver Script in ReplicatedStorage as well, and that isn't one of the locations that Scripts execute. According to [the documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Script) :

> The instant that the following conditions are met, a Script’s Lua code is run in a new thread:
>
> - Disabled property is false
> - The Script object is a descendant of the Workspace or
>   ServerScriptService

So your BindableEvent is probably firing correctly, but the Script you have to listen for the event is never running, so it is never connecting to the event. Try moving the Script into the Workspace or ServerScriptService and update the path to the Event.